# Boolean sets to false by itself

Tags: c#

my problem is that `bool rememberMe` automaticly sets its value to false, i don't know why

```
public partial class Example1 : Form
{
    public Example1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool rememberMe;

    public void TryLogin()
    {
        if (checkboxRememberMe.Checked)
        rememberMe = true;
        else
        rememberMe = false;
        var e2 = new Example2();
    }

    public bool CheckRememberMe()
    {
        if (rememberMe == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

public partial class Example2 : Form
{
    public Example2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var lf = new Example1();
        if (lf.CheckRememberMe() == true)
            // ...
        else
            // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is Windows Forms App. First is `TryLogin()` method, which sets `rememberMe` to `true`. Then, the `public Example2()` runs. The problem is that in this part of script

```
var lf = new LoginForm();
if (lf.CheckRememberMe() == true)
    // ...
else
    // ...
```

shows that `lf.CheckRememberMe()` equals `false`. What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: That's because you never run `TryLogin` function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Please rename `Example1` and `Example2` to meaningful class names. Also, what is `LoginForm`, is it actually `Example1`?

Comment: @Fabjan i do, but i didn't write this script here cause it would be too long

Comment: @Progman yeah, LoginForm is actually example1, sorry for mistake, i've edited it and now should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var lf = new LoginForm();
```

This creates a **new** LoginForm - so it won't have the changes that the other login form made.

You will have to pass the variable, or make it static.

Try changing the constructor to:

```
public Example2(bool rememberMe){
    this.rememberMe = rememberMe;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then passing it:

```
var e2 = new Example2(rememberMe);
```

Or you could (but probably shouldn't) change it to a static variable:

```
public static bool rememberMe;
```

And reference by class name:

```
if (Example1.rememberMe == true)
```

If you just want to get it working quickly - but then read up on Object Oriented basics

Comment: oh, thanks! making the bool static worked! reaaaaaallyyyy thank u man

Comment: @CodeBr3akerSon Do read up on WHY this worked though, as it is not *proper* scalable design to do it this way

Comment: You should pay attention when he says you probably shouldn't do this. Setting it to static means that every instance of your class will share this variable. Changing the value on one will change it on every instance. `false` is the default value of a boolean. It will be false until you set it to something else. Either call `TryLogin` before you check if `rememberMe == true` or not, or make rememberMe a nullable boolean that way it will be null until you set it to either true or false. Making it static is NOT a good option.